# Correctly getting a frame as bitmap from a video in good quality

Tags: android, video, android-mediacodec, mediametadataretriever

I am trying to get the last frame from a video as a bitmap in good quality. I am now using MediaMetadataRetriever with the method getFrameAtTime, but the picture quality is very poor - see a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31789609/android-bitmap-compress-poor-quality-with-png-format).

I tried to use this method here:

https://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#ExtractMpegFramesTest but I cannot get it to work, the frames are all just horizontal lines

Also, another library that is very interesting: https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever 
This one can get very good quality images from frames, but it only has at-second precision (for example if I try to get the last frame or a frame at 2300ms, it only shows corrupted image)

Are there any other options?